# Error trying to access converted C# project from VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

Beginner here. I'm trying to move over to C# for the future, so I want to convert my main project to it. I'm tried using SharpDevelop 4.4, but after converting attempting to open my forms in Visual Studio results in:

```
To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:

    The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed.
```

and the error:

```
    Instances of this error (1)  

    1.   Hide Call Stack  
    at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
    at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

Is there a way I can manually convert the files? I know there are code converters online, but I have no idea how you would change the entire solution.

---

Edit: Getting this error after trying to run the program:

```
   Error   5   The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Skype.Converted.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  This error may also appear if some other project is trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this project has been unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent Configuration or Platform.   Skype.Converted
```

And an info message:

```
Message    4   The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed.
```

Comment: I think if you dig a bit deeper there will be a bit more detail about what is wrong with the form. There should be a more helpful error message in there. Keep digging and report back if you find something.

Comment: Make sure the Control/UserControl/Component class is the first class in the file. If its not, it won't load the designer.

Comment: I'm not convinced that SharpDevelop's Form Designer is compatible with Visual Studio's (I certainly haven't been able to make the same designer file work with VB in both SharpDevelop and Visual Studio). You may need to design a new form in Visual Studio and then copy the C# code for the event handlers and other user written code from the .cs file created by SharpDevelop into the file you created in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes you can manually convert.  I would create an empty C# project and then move the code from the old basic project into the new C# project.  The form has a designer.vb or a designer.cs which are ascii files that can be edited.  Converting the code is usually very simple and have done it plenty of times before.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this code converter, as it's the one I've used when I've only been able to find solutions to my answers in C# and need them in VB.

I'm sure you could use it for the reverse action to manually convert your code.

Link: http://converter.telerik.com/

As far as the designer bits are concerned, I'm relatively certain you can select all of your controls on one project, copy, and then paste them onto the other project. Re-associating them with their functions/handles will be annoying though.